# Regex pegar determinado tamanho de dígitos e ou com simbolo

Tags: php

Pessoal como pegar os dígitos de **tamanho 9**, e que tenha ou não um sinal de exclamação (!) no final.

Exemplo:

```
 blabla n123456789 bla bla 78 texto...
 987654321! texto qualquer 12 blaa
 123 bla blum 123741852 bobobl
 blablum 12345678901 papumpa...
```

Saída:

```
 123456789
 987654321!
 123741852
```

No meu Regex, trás "cortado" os dígitos superior a 9

```
 preg_match_all('/[!\d]{9,10}/', $a, $match);
 print_r($match);
```

Saída:

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
(
     [0] => 123456789
     [1] => 987654321!
     [2] => 123741852
     [3] => 1234567890 // <- FALHA
)

 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

essa expressão deve servir

```
\d{9}
```

https://regex101.com/r/fY8sN3/1

---

Update

para exibir o ! junto

```
\d{9}!?
```

--

Uma solução pra essa outra é

```
\b\d{9}!?\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/fY8sN3/3

Comment: E quanto ao sinal de exclamação (!) ?

Comment: vc quer exibi-lo também?

Comment: sim quero @AdirKuhn

Comment: Legal @AdirKuhn, pra ficar perfeito só falta ele ignorar o dígitos superior a 9. No exemplo acima na última linha que contem 11 dígitos ele corta

Comment: Obrigado @AdirKuhn

Answer (score 4):

Mais complicado do que parece !

Para lidar com todos os casos possíveis acredito que essa seja uma regex correta:

```
(?:^|(?<=[^\d]))\d{9}(?:!|(?=[^\d])|$)
```

Ela "diz" mais ou menos o seguinte: "me dê todos os grupos de 9 números que (sejam precedidos por algo que não é um número Ou que sejam o início da string) E (que sejam seguidos por uma exclamação Ou por algo que não é um número Ou pelo fim da string).".

https://regex101.com/r/hC8cN6/2 contêm a validação da regex para o seu caso de teste e para algumas outras situações possíveis de acordo com a descrição do problema.

Comment: Muito bom não conhecia essas regex, mais coisa pra estudar =D

Answer (score 1):

A solução do Adir é boa, só um pequeno detalhe,
deveria ser

```
\b\d{9}\b!?
```

para exibir sim ou não o !